# Debian: Bash email using TCP

Tags: bash, email, tcp, openssl, debian

On a server I am currently receiving intermittent '421 Unexpected failure, please try later' in the logs generated using Swiftmailer.

In order to debug this, using the command:

```
    openssl s_client -crlf -connect www.somesite:443
```

I can successfully send an email.

I would like to put all of the negotiation etc in a bash script in order for me to run it repeatedly and see if any particular case invokes the 421 error.

I have came across several examples using the syntax:

```
    exec $fd<>"/dev/tcp/${SERVER}/${PORT}"
```

however as noted in other answers this needs to be enabled when building bash and Debian does not enable this.

Other than recompiling bash with this setting (--enable-net-redirections I think) does anyone no of any alternatives?

would it be possible to some way inside a bash script exec the openssl command and read the output write to input? e.g.

```
    exec $fd<>`openssl s_client -crlf -connect www.somesite:443`
```

Comment: It looks like you are connecting to a website, and *not* sending email with `s_client`. Usually with email, your command would use `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.example.com:465` or similar. See [`s_client(1)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) command.

Comment: When I attempted to connect using -starttls smtp the only repsonse from the server was:
CONNECTED(00000003)
without that I could connect properly and send an email however that is not the question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've figured I can use expect instead of the $fd<> to do what I'm after so the relevant section of the script that handles the raw mail negotiation becomes:

```
    expect <<- DONE
        log_user 0
        spawn -noecho openssl s_client -crlf -connect ${MailHost}:${MailPort}
        expect { 
            "*220 *" {}
            timeout { log_user 1; send_user "Invalid response from server\n"; exit 1}
        }

        send -- "EHLO ${MyHost}\r"
        expect { 
            "250 *" {}
            timeout { log_user 1; send_user "Handshake Failed\n"; exit 1}
        }

        send -- "AUTH LOGIN\r"
        expect { 
            "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6" {}
            timeout { log_user 1; send_user "Unexpected username prompt\n"; exit 1}
        }

        send -- "${AuthUser}\r"
        expect { 
            "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6" {}
            "535 *" { log_user 1; send_user "535 Incorrect authentication data\n"; exit 1}
            timeout { log_user 1; send_user "Unexpected password prompt\n"; exit 1}
        }

        send -- "${AuthPass}\r"
        expect { 
            "*235 *" {}
            timeout { log_user 1; send_user "Authentication Failed\n"; exit 1}
        }

        send -- "MAIL FROM:<${FromAddr}>\r"
        expect { 
            "250 *" {}
            timeout { log_user 1; send_user "Error setting From Address\n"; exit 1}
        }

        send -- "rcpt TO:<${ToAddr}>\r"
        expect { 
            "250 *" {}
            timeout { log_user 1; send_user "Error setting Recipient Address\n"; exit 1}
        }

        send -- "DATA\r"
        expect { 
            "354 *" {}
            timeout { log_user 1; send_user "Error setting Data\n"; exit 1}
        }

        send -- "Subject: ${Subject}\r\r${Message}\r\r.\r\r"
        expect { 
            "250 *" {}
            timeout { log_user 1; send_user "Error sending email\n"; exit 1}
        }
    DONE
```